# How to create reusable dropdown component using material ui or mui in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Any solution to create reusable dropdown component using material ui or mui in react ?

Comment: Here's a video you can take reference from. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnhamYM3Ubo

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Material UI - Autocomplete component to create the reusable dropdown component.

[image]

Here is the documentation and code example inside:

https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#main-content